# PCA with high amount of repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, factor-analysis

I want to create a system that can automatically evaluate a session as success or a failure. Each session generates a lot of data points, and thus I want to start my modeling with dimensionality reduction. My problem is that my subject pool is not very high [~fifty], but each subject performs several hundred sessions. I read that it is possible to use Multiple Factor Analysis to solve the problem of repeated measures, but is it OK even when the sessions:subjects ratio is high?